# DTS Jobs to Offline Databases

Tags: sql-server, networking, jobs, dts

I have a machine running SQL Server 2008, with 6 different databases; 3 of them are offline. In my network, several computers are connecting to my SqlServer to perform certain tasks. Some of them haves jobs(DTS) that are still pointing to my offline databases. Is there a way to know which jobs are trying to perform tasks on my offline databases?

Comment: When you say "jobs(DTS)", do you literally mean that the jobs are executing **DTS** packages (old packages, like from SQL Server 2000)?  Or are the jobs executing **SSIS** packages (which is current/typical, for SQL Server 2008)?

Comment: Old packages...the other machines haves SQLSVR 2000 and their jobs access the machine with SQLSVR 2008, but some of those jobs are pointing to offline databases.

Comment: Do you have access to the `msdb` database, on the SS2000 machines?  If so, then try accessing the table `msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages`, and look at the DTS package contents in column `packagedata`.  (Note: I don't have access to a SQL Server 2000 environment right now, to test this... so I won't submit this as an answer... just give it a try, and comment-back, how that's going.  I got this idea from 'Method 2', about package copying, at **[this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/02/19/how-to-copy-dts-2000-packages-between-servers-and-from-sql-2000-to-sql-2005-and-sql-2008.aspx)**.)

Comment: Still no luck....i think i'm gonna do it the hard way(check every machine Sql Agent log) to detect the problem; once detected and localized, then edit those jobs...it's gonna be a loooong day xD

Comment: Well, if checking job logs, then you can at least speed THAT process up:  take a look at the tables `msdb..sysjobhistory` and `msdb..sysjobs`, and search for your error messages.  Something like `select distinct b.name,a.run_date,right('00000'+convert(varchar,a.run_time),6),message from msdb..sysjobhistory a  inner join msdb..sysjobs b on a.job_id = b.job_id  where run_status <> 1   and lower(message) like '%that connection error message%' and (lower(message) like '%error%'  or lower(message) like '%fail%') and CONVERT(CHAR(8), a.run_date, 112) >= '20131126'`

Comment: For more detail on the errors, you could also include table `msdb..sysjobsteps`, to get columns `subsystem`, `database_name`, and `command`.  Append a `join` to the select above, like `left outer join msdb..sysjobsteps  steps  steps.job_id = a.job_id  and steps.[step_id] = a.[step_id]`.  (You only need a `left outer join` if a job may terminate very early, like in the launch step... in which case it will not show steps in the history.)